# Optimal Number of Realizations for a Discrete Stochastic Process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, statistical-inference

I have a curiosity concerning discrete stochastic processes. Let us say we have a discrete stochastic process $X_{i} = \left(x_1,x_2,...x_i,...,x_N \right)$, hence we have N random variables with an unknown statistical distribution. 
Let us say now that we have M of these random vectors so we have M realizations of my stochastic process. Is there any mathematical result about the "optimal" number of M we need in order to infer the statistics of each random variable $x_i$ ?

Intuitively I would say that M has to be equal or greater than N but it is just a guess without any kind of prove. I am not a mathematician and for this reason I am asking to someone way more expert than me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**The best number of sample values is a full census of the population (i.e., $n=N$):** In any problem like this, where you are sampling-without-replacement from a finite population, if you sample $n=N$ values, you will have observed all the population values in your sample, so there is no statistical inference problem left --- i.e., as soon as you have sampled $n=N$ values there is nothing left to "infer".  (And you certainly don't need to keep sampling after you have already observed all the values in the population.)

If there is no cost or other limitation that would prevent a full census of the population then that is going to give you the most accurate results.  You just observe all $n=N$ values, write them down, and then you have a full description of the population.  Statistical inference arises when this is infeasible (e.g., when sampling has a cost), so that we need to rely on a sample that is smaller than the full population.  Higher values of $0 \leqslant n \leqslant N$ give more data, which gives more information for the inference of the remaining unobserved values.  Thus, in practice, sample sizes are usually determined by deciding how much data you need to get an inference at a desired level of accuracy, while minimising cost.

Comment: Thanks! Surely I wasn't clear! I'll try with an example. I generate a Gaussian noise of length 500 samples. This vector will be my first realization of my stochastic process. Let's say that we do not know already that each point of my vector follow a Gaussian distribution. What I can do is generate more of these random vectors (M) and at this point I can create an histogram for each of my 500 points which will have M counts. How much has to be M in order to start to see a decent Gaussian? Someone can argue more as much as you can but the I am exactly looking for a kind of "optimal" number.

Comment: More data will always get you a better estimate, so if you are looking for an "optimal" number that is not trivial (i.e., as much data as possible) then you would have to specify some cost to the sampling, and specify what it is that you are trying to optimise (presumably some measure that weights accuracy of the inference against the costs of the data).  Without doing this, you are essentially just asking, "How do I optimise this monotonically increasing function?"

Comment: Thanks again Ben! I see the point now. So I need to define a kind of measure otherwise the reply "as much as we can" is the only answer! Cheers!